# Reading Mail from Office 365 Mailbox - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, office365

I have a requirement where I need to read the mail from office 365 Mailbox using node js. I saw this package [node-outlook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-outlook), the problem is how to get oauth token to use this node module? Because this is going to be completely a background job, there is no user interaction involved.

Answer (score 1):

To get the token you have to create a microsoft App and authenticate. It will return the token. I think the `node-outlook` docs doesn't provide enough documentation for this. For more please refer this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview